# Как вывести данные из внешнего JSON кода

Tags: python, json

[image: Внешний JSON]

`Curr = response['currencies']['name']['symbol']`

Вывод должен быть: Kazakhstani tenge "₸"

Как правильно ввести путь, ведь путь всегда разный:

[image: Пример с Францией]

EUR, KZT, RUB, USD и так далее

Какой общий путь к строке?

Answer (score 0):

Просто переберите элементы словаря:

```
for alias, curr in response['currencies'].items():
    print(alias, curr['name'], curr['symbol'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CurrTitle = list(response['currencies'].values())
CurrTitle1 = CurrTitle[0]['name']
SymCurr = list(response['currencies'].values())
SymCurr1 = SymCurr[0]['symbol']
```

Создал два значения CurrTitle = Название(Euro, Kazakhstani Tenge)
SymCurr = Символ валюты